# possibility of yield farming with flashloan

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

is there possible to do a yield farming with flashloan? I can performed simple arbitrage with one single call back function.

but can I perform 2 call back function with Aave without executing 2 transactions instead of one, which I tried and it shows 2 tx in polyscan?

The simple function should be as such:
first callback to trigger deposit, and wait for 20 second the trigger second callback to withdraw and repayment?

Answer (score 1):

Money loaned in flashloans must be returned in the *same* transaction, otherwise they will revert. This means that you can't perform any more than one transaction with the same loan.

[Read more on flashloans here](https://cointelegraph.com/explained/what-are-flash-loans-in-defi#:%7E:text=Simply%20put%2C%20in%20a%20flash,charged%20a%20fee%20of%200.09%25.)

Quote from that link:

> If any of the following conditions occur, the transaction is reversed, and the funds are returned to the lender:
>
> - The borrower does not repay the capital (within the same transaction)
> - The trade does not lead to a profit